# R plot with counting

Tags: r, bar-chart

For a range of data arranged like this:

```
 Class 1      Class 2
   1          1
   2          2
   3          3
   4          4 
   5          5
   .          .
   .          .
   .          .
   1,000,000  2,000,000
```

How can I build a barplot which has the two classes as axes labels and where I have two separate groups of bars, one for each class where the height of each bar shows how many values from my data are bigger than that value?

Comment: Based on the example provided, what do you want as the x-axis labels.  If I understand correctly, You may need to use `cut` to get different grouping for each `class` and then get the `table` based on that grouping and plot.  For that, you have to specify the `breaks` argument.  I would say the description is not clear.  Also, using `...` is not helpful.  It would be better to show a small dataset.

Comment: Two axis labels class 1 and class 2. Each will correspond to a group of bars where the height value shows how many values from my data are bigger than that value. e.g if the height of the bar is 5, it shows how many values are bigger than 5

Comment: `how many values from my data are bigger than that value?`  Do you have a threshold value?

Comment: Do you  want something like this?  `set.seed(24);
df1 <- data.frame(Class1= sample(0:20, 100, replace=TRUE), Class2= sample(4:10, 100, replace=TRUE));barplot(colSums(df1>5))`

Comment: Or are you comparing the number of rows in Class1 is greater than Class2 and viceversa like here. `indx <- df1[,1] > df1[,2];
barplot(colSums(cbind(Class1=indx, Class2=!indx)))`

Comment: If the second class is ignored,  I will have multiple bars and each will count how many values from my dataset are greater or equal to some value of the y axis. If I calibrate the y axis as >5,>6,>7 I would expect three bars counting how many entries from class 1 are bigger than 5,6 and 7

Comment: Try `barplot(setNames(colSums(sapply(5:7, `<`,df1[,1])), 5:7))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop '5:7' (`sapply`), get a logical matrix by checking whether the first column i.e 'class1' is greater (`>`) than each element, do the `colSums`, name the frequency with `setNames` and plot the bars using `barplot`.

```
 barplot(setNames(colSums(sapply(5:7, '<',df1[,1])), paste0('>', 5:7)))
```

[image]

NOTE: Figure is based on OP's comments.

#### Update

If we want both the 'Class1' and 'Class2' bars adjacent to each other for each comparison with 5, 6, and 7, we do the same loop with `sapply`, compare with the full dataset ('df1'), get the `colSums`, change the column names of the output matrix with labels '>5', '>6', '>7' using `paste` and then plot with `barplot`

```
 m1 <- sapply(5:7, function(x) colSums(df1 >x))
 colnames(m1) <-  paste0('>', 5:7)
 barplot(m1, beside=TRUE, legend=TRUE)
```

[image]

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Class1= sample(0:20, 100, replace=TRUE), 
            Class2= sample(4:10, 100, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: is it possible to rearrange and have two >5 columns groupped together one for each class, then another two for >6 and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Because I thought you meant for all values, rather than some chosen.

Using the data from @akrun:

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(Class1= sample(0:20, 100, replace=TRUE), 
                  Class2= sample(4:10, 100, replace=TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
```

Then we make a cumulative amount column, with added 0s for ggplot to know we aren't just missing data.

```
z <- df1 %>% melt %>%
             group_by(variable, value) %>%
             summarise(number = n()) %>%
             left_join(expand.grid("value" = unique(.[["value"]]), "variable" = levels(.[["variable"]])), .) %>%
             mutate(number = ifelse(is.na(number), 0, number))  %>%          
             group_by(variable) %>%
             mutate(above = 1-cumsum(number/sum(number))) 

ggplot(z, aes(x = factor(value), weight = above, fill = variable)) + 
       geom_bar(position= "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: OP said in the comments that the comparison is only for `5, 6, 7`